# Why is the total space complexity of bubble sort O(1) according to Wikipedia?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, bubble-sort, space-complexity

Based on [This article on GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-86/) and the questions posted on [StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108505/difference-between-auxiliary-space-v-s-space-complexity/108512) and [Quroa](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Auxiliary-space-and-space-complexity), the space complexity of an algorithm is the space it takes to solve a problem including the space that the input takes, and the auxiliary space is any extra storage that the algorithm needs besides the input itself to solve the problem.

Now I get that the auxiliary space of the bubble sort is O(1) since it only takes one variable to keep track of the number of swaps we are making to see when the list is sorted (correct me if I'm wrong), but why does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) say that the total space complexity of the bubble sort is O(1) as well?

Isn't it supposed to be O(n) considering the input itself?

Comment: This is because, we always consider the **extra space** used and not the space used in the input itself. These type of algorithms are usually called **in-place algorithms**.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Based on the links above there is a distinction between **space complexity** and **auxiliary space** and the space complexity is the total used storage used by an algorithm including the input, Wikipedia explicitly says that both the space complexity and the auxiliary space of the bubble sort is O(1). If what you're saying is true, then why does Wikipedia say that the total space complexity of insertion sort is O(n) and the auxiliary space is O(1)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: So, I think this is because if you use a recursive insertion sort, it takes up O(n) stack space. But the auxilary space is still O(1). This is not a concern for iterative insertion sort.

Comment: Please present the quote from Wikipedia. I see in the right summary panel of that wiki page: *"Worst-case space complexity: O(n) total, O(1) auxiliary"*. I don't see the problem. Input = O(n) space, Auxiliary = O(1), so total = Input+Auxiliary = O(n).

Comment: @trincot It was corrected by someone after this post today. Thanks for the answer though. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bubble_sort&diff=next&oldid=1003079586

Comment: @trincot It did say *`O(1)` total* space for Bubble Sort before. I did check it myself. It must be wrong so someone must have corrected it.

Comment: Good catch then! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does Wikipedia say that the total space complexity of the bubble sort is O(1) as well?

Good catch! It was corrected in the mean time. It now says the total space complexity is O(n). Quoted from the summary panel at the right:

> **Worst-case space complexity** O() total, O(1) auxiliary

So:

- The input has a space complexity of O()
- In addition, O(1) is needed for the algorithm = auxiliary space
- The total space used consists of input and auxiliary space, so O()+O(1) = O()

Comment: It was corrected by someone after this post today. Thanks for the answer though. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bubble_sort&diff=next&oldid=1003079586

Answer (score 1):

By the term `space complexity` it defines that the amount of extra memory your algorithm takes. if you required to allocation an array of size `N` it would mean your algorithm takes `O(N)` extra space or more specifically auxiliary space.

But in case of bubble-sort, we can use only single variable (for swapping purpose) to make things happen.

so overall space complexity is `O(N)` which includes your input, and overall auxiliary space complexity is `O(1)`

In Wikipedia by `overall space complexity` it defines auxiliary space.

Comment: Based on the links above there is a distinction between space complexity and auxiliary space and the space complexity is the total used storage used by an algorithm including the input, Wikipedia explicitly says that both the space complexity and the auxiliary space of the bubble sort is O(1). If what you're saying is true, then why does Wikipedia say that the total space complexity of insertion sort is O(n) and the auxiliary space is O(1)? en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: Yes you and links are saying right! It's my bad! If you consider your input too, then yes, the space complexity is O(N) , but if you're not consider your input (auxiliary space complexity) it is O(1). I will edit my answer.